# Websocket client getting 200 response code

Tags: websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a nodejs server to serve both http and websocket on the same port. The setup works fine on localhost, but when deployed on Amazon Beanstalk (which has a loadbalancer and nginx), the ws client throws an error when establishing ws connection: "Unexpected response code 200". I am not 100% certain about this but I think it's because the nodejs server somehow mistakes ws handshake request as a http request and thus returns 200. Here is the code for my server:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var indexPage = "Loading index page, try again later?";

fs.readFile('./index.html',function (err,data){
    indexPage = data;
})
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
});
server.listen(1337, function() { });

// create the server
wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

// WebSocket server
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    console.dir(request);
    var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    console.log("connected");
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log("Received",message.utf8Data);
        }
    });
    connection.on('close', function(connection) {
    });
});
```

Any suggestions for me? How should I config nginx and loadbalancer in this case?

Answer (score 0):

typically on node.js hosting services they supply an environment variable which is dynamically created on their end per launch of your app - this is typical :

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
```

then when launched locally without the env var it just uses your favorite 1337

Comment: As in my code above, I fixed the port to be 1337 and have checked nodejs server log, no error was found.